# Unable to find Webview on Real Android Device Running 5.1.1

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

Webview is not available in Hybrid application with Real Android Device running version 5.1.1 with Appium.

Same thing is working fine with Emulator on same android/Appium version.

Answer (score 0):

Webview applications appear as native application on Andriod 5. If you want to automate the application in webview format of code, set the automation capability : automation-name  to  Selendroid and set the context to webview.

```
foreach(String context in driver.contexts())
{
   if(context.contains("WebView"){
    driver.context = context;
    }
}
```

If you do not have html content for the screen to find the selectors, insert code

```
Console.Writeline(driver.pagesource).
```

That way you get html's as well to pick selectors

Comment: I have done the same. it's working for emulator. but its not working on real device

Comment: driver.contexts() contains only native app in case of Real device. in case of Emulator i can see webview as one of the context.

Comment: On device , have you run the test with automation-name as selendroid? When testing with seledriod, appium expects the apk file in app path. Set that as well

Comment: tried setting the same but still its not working on real device.

Comment: what is the app value you have setup in the capability?

Comment: you can refer to log @ https://gist.github.com/kuldeepvasani/7a1ea3c8bf753b3e47b7#file-appiumerror

Comment: App seems ok. But you still using automation name as appium. "automationName":"Appium". I doubt you will get webview when you use automationName as  appium. Try automationName as selendriod or try autoWebview as true . Here is the server capabilities doc http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#appium-server-capabilities

Answer (score 0):

Important points for webviews in Android

1. **WebView requires** Android **version 4.4 or later** i.e. **API level >=19**.
2. WebView debugging should be enabled; developer must **enable** **‘setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled’ flag** in the **WebView class**. This flag enables debugging of web contents (HTML / CSS / JavaScript) loaded into any WebViews of app.
3. Appium also uses Selendroid under the hood for webview support on devices older than 4.4. To use this feature of appium, it is mandatory to specify “automationName” as “selendroid” in desired capabilities passed to Appium server.
4. If our hybrid app under test is build in such a way that it supports minimum Android version 4.0.4 (API Level 14) and max Android version 4.3 (API level 18) then we can inspect webview elements and execute our automation tests using selendroid mode of appium.